# Generic Queue in C with run time data types

Tags: c, function-pointers, singly-linked-list, vtable

I want to create a linked list which can accept any data type at run time and display the list. The problem is display function and memory management changes for different data types. So I don't know how to do that. Code examples will be appreciated.

Edit: to narrow down the problem. this is queue structure(using linked list)

```
struct node         
{
    void *data; 
    struct node *link; 
};

struct queue
{
    struct node *front; 
    struct node *rear;  
};
```

Now the caller functions for addition of new element and display are as follows:

```
int main()
{
    struct queue* q;
    void *a;
    char ch;
    printf("do you want to add an element?(y/n)\n");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    while(ch!=n)
    {
        printf("Enter the element\n");
        scanf("%p",a);
        enqueue(q,a);
        display(q);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Following is my enqueue function definition:

```
void enqueue(struct queue* queue,void* item)
{
    if(queue->logical_length==queue->cnt_max)
    {
        printf("Queue is full\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node*temp;
        temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->data=malloc(queue->data_size);
        temp->link=NULL;
        memcpy(temp->data,item,queue->data_size);
        if(queue->front==NULL)
        {
            queue->rear=queue->front=temp;
            queue->logical_length=queue->logical_length+1;
            return;
        }
        queue->rear->link=temp;
        queue->rear=temp;
        queue->logical_length=queue->logical_length+1;  
    }
}
```

Here, the problem is how to allocate memory to data field if I don't even know the data type. So if there is some way to find data type of runtime entered values it will be better.

Following is my display function:

```
void display(struct queue* queue)
{
    struct node* temp;
    if(queue->front==NULL)
    {
        printf("Queue is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        temp=queue->front;
        while(temp->link!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%p \t",*(void *)temp->data);
            temp=temp->link;
        }
        printf("%p \t",*(void *)temp->data);
    }
}
```

Here the output is always some random numbers.

Comment: You should think about, and tell us, a little more about what you're trying to do, and maybe set some limits.  In full generality, what you're talking about sounds like it might require implementing some/all of C++ on top of C.  (Which can certainly be done, after all that's the way Bjarne did it the first time, but it's some work!)

Comment: C is a "strongly typed" language. Although there are ways to defeat it, is C the right language for you?

Comment: FWIW: the linux kernel has some *generic* LLs, implemented with a set of macros.

Comment: use `void *` as holding data. and display function need user function for `void *`.

Comment: I added `function-pointers` and `vtable` tags, as that is what you're going to have to use.

Comment: can you do it more like object oriented, e.g supply pointer to show functiin. memory management probably not need, because you always can do free() and insert function may get void *

Comment: Note that your `struct queue` doesn't have members `logical_length` or `cnt_max`, which means your code isn't going to compile.

Comment: You can do the storing of the data in either of two ways.  One is that the function calling `insert` hands over control of the storage to the queue; the extract function returns control back to the calling code.  This means the queue doesn't need to know how much data is pointed at.  The other is that you tell the `insert` function how big the chunk of data is as well as where it is stored.  However, this means you are limited to data structures that can be copied (using `memmove()` or equivalent) safely.  Many structures can't be copied like that (think structures containing pointers).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the storing of the data in either of two ways.

1. The function calling `insert` hands over control of the storage to the queue; the extract function returns control back to the calling code.  This means the queue doesn't need to know how much data is pointed at.
2. You tell the `insert` function how big the chunk of data is as well as where it is stored (`void enqueue(struct queue *queue, void *item, size_t length)`).  However, this means you are limited to data structures that can be copied (using `memmove()` or equivalent) safely.  Many structures can't be copied like that (think structures containing pointers).

For the first mechanism, the `display()` function is altered into an `apply()` function which is given a function pointer:

```
void apply(struct queue *queue, void *data, void (*function)(const void *item, void *data));
```

The `queue` is traversed, and the function is called with the current item from the queue plus the data passed to the `apply` function.  This data is a pointer to whatever context is needed to make the function work properly.  For displaying, it might be a `FILE *`, or it might be a more complex structure.  Either way, the function (that is pointed at by the function pointer `function`) knows what to do with the data because it is attuned to the data type.

Comment: 2nd way is not really possible as i have mentioned that we can't tell the size of data. about the first one, i didn't really get it. can you please elaborate